# Microphone not detected when using 3.5mm splitter

Tags: audio, headphones, microphone

I use a Mac Mini and bought myself a headphone splitter so that I don't have to fiddle about when I need to use my microphone... e.g I don't want to have to unplug my speakers whenever I have a Skype call.

When I have my microphone plugged into the 3.5mm splitter my Mac won't detect my microphone, although my speakers work just fine. I've also tried it with two different splitters.

Is it not possible to get it to work this way?

Comment: Do the splitters have 3 conductors (TRS) or 4 (TRRS)?

Comment: See https://www.cablechick.com.au/blog/understanding-trrs-and-audio-jacks/ for a plug guide

Comment: Thanks both, I realise now that the splitter was only for headphones! I imagine I'll need to order this instead https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B079PJL14Y